# Expo Camera onReady doesn't work: Integration with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, expo, expo-camera

When connecting Expo Camera with TensorFlow, the **handleCameraStream** method I've created doesn't load initially; it only works when I re-render the device, but not initially. I think the issue lies with the Expo Camera props **onReady**. Do you have a solution for this?

```
<TensorCamera
  type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
  // Tensor related props
  cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
  cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
  resizeHeight={200}
  resizeWidth={152}
  resizeDepth={3}
  onReady={handleCameraStream}
  autorender={true}
 />
```